# Template class derived from nontemplate class: access to derived class' generic variable

Tags: c++, templates

**SOLVED!**

I want to create an array of different typed objects using templates.
Therefore I have a non-template class (Base), and a derived template class from Base class.

What I want to know is how can i access to derived class' generic value (T val)?

```
class Base{
public:

    // a function returns T val, it will be implemented in Derived class

    // EDIT : virtual function here

};

template<class T>
class Derived: public Base {

public:
    T val;

    Derived(T x) {
        val = x;
    }

    // implementation.. it returns val

    // EDIT : Implementation of virtual function
};
```

**Solution:** dynamic_cast, Note that Base class should have at least one virtual function.

```
Base *p[2];
p[0] = new Derived<int>(24);
p[1] = new Derived<double>(82.56);

int a = dynamic_cast<Derived<int>*>(p[0])->val;        // casts p[0] to Derived<int>*
double b = dynamic_cast<Derived<double>*>(p[1])->val;  // casts p[1] to Derived<double>*

cout << a << endl; 
cout << b << endl;
```

Comment: why cant you make the base class templated too?

Comment: you cannot acess derived class members from base class...so, you can pass it to base class if it accepts a parameter

Comment: I'm trying to create an array that holds different typed objects. I tried to make an array of 'template class' but I had to specify its type like this:
    Derived<int>p[10]. But array should hold any type of objects

Comment: what parameter should I use?

Comment: How you are intending to use such a function? Remember that any function and any variable in C++ must have a fixed type.

Comment: I guess template functions returns generic type of data but i couldnt implement it.

Comment: Is it possible cast of base class object to derived class?

Comment: Use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/any.html

Answer (score 0):

Last time i checked, You cannot acess derived class members from a base class(non virtual).

You could modify your code this way since you are using templates.The type and value are passed to base class at construction and you can then use it.

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
   T ini;
public:
    Base(T arg){ini = arg;}
    T ret(){return ini;}
};

template<class T>
class Derived: public Base<T> {

public:
    T val;

    Derived(T x) : Base<T>(x) {
        //Base(x);
        val = x;
    }

    // implementation.. it returns val
};
```

You can then instantiate it as usual and use it.

```
Derived<int>  e(5);    
e.ret();
```

Comment: Is it possible like following code?
Base *p[10];
 p[0] = new Derived<int>(5);

Comment: I get an error: missing template arguments before 'p'

Comment: @luo This solution will restrict your array to `int`elements. Look at Christians comment for a generic container.

Comment: if you need an array, use Derived<int>* p[10];

Comment: @basav array should be generic not just ints, thanks anyway :)

Comment: i dont understand generic here.....derived<anytype>...that is why u use templates, right

Comment: derived<int>(5), derived<double>(2.25), derived<string>("something"). I want all of them in one array

Answer (score 0):

It look like you want CRTP

The idea is to access the derived class members inside the base class. Note that you won't be able to contain an heterogeneous list of them.

```
template<typename D>
struct Base {
    void doThings() {
        // access the derived class getT function
        auto var = static_cast<D&>(*this).getT();

        cout << var << endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base<Derived> {
    T getT() {
        return myT;
    }

private:
    T myT;
};
```